# Tensorflow equivalent of Pytorch FloatTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

How can I implement this line of code with just using tensorflow?

```
self.kernel = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(embedding_size, num_groups))
        nn.init.normal_(self.kernel, std=0.01)
```

Comment: It is tf.Tensor() kindly check api-docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimum reproducable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I want to create a loss function for similarity learning. I am implementing ArcFace loss for implementation, I need a tensor for includes embeding size and number of classes.